# Cannot find source file error when running CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

Error from Terminal:

```
ics45c@ics45c-2019fall : ~/projects/proj1 $ ./build app
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:49 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

    /home/ics45c/projects/proj1/app/.#main.cpp

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
  .hxx .in .txx


CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: a.out.gtest
CMake Error: Cannot determine link language for target "a.out.gtest".
CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: a.out.app
CMake Error: Cannot determine link language for target "a.out.app".
CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: a.out.exp
CMake Error: Cannot determine link language for target "a.out.exp".
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/ics45c/projects/proj1/out
```

I checked my file manager and `main.cpp` and `#main.cpp#` are in the location `/home/ics45c/projects/proj1/app`

Also I don't understand the other CMake errors after CMakeLists.txt either. What does it mean that it can't determine the linker language?

```
## Here is the CMakeLists.txt file ##

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER clang)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER clang++)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

set(COMPILE_FLAGS "-stdlib=libc++ -Wall -pedantic-errors -Werror -g -fstandalone-debug")


project(a.out.app)

file(GLOB APP_SRC_FILES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/app/*.cpp)

set(APP_SRC_FILES_EXCEPT_MAIN ${APP_SRC_FILES})
list(REMOVE_ITEM APP_SRC_FILES_EXCEPT_MAIN ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/app/main.cpp)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${APP_SRC_FILES})
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS ${COMPILE_FLAGS})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/app)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} pthread c++)

project(a.out.exp)

file(GLOB EXP_SRC_FILES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/exp/*.cpp)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${EXP_SRC_FILES} ${APP_SRC_FILES_EXCEPT_MAIN})
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS ${COMPILE_FLAGS})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/app)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/exp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} pthread c++)


project(a.out.gtest)

file(GLOB GTEST_SRC_FILES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/gtest/*.cpp)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${GTEST_SRC_FILES} ${APP_SRC_FILES_EXCEPT_MAIN})
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS ${COMPILE_FLAGS})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/app)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/gtest)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} pthread c++ gtest gtest_main)
```

**Line 49** is the error according to the CMake error but I have no idea why:

```
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${GTEST_SRC_FILES} ${APP_SRC_FILES_EXCEPT_MAIN})
```

I just don't understand any of this, and this is also my first Stackoverflow post.

Comment: It's looking for `/home/ics45c/projects/proj1/app/.#main.cpp` which is quite an unusual name for a source file.  Also not sure if the `#` is causing an issue.

Comment: That's what I was thinking too but I have no idea why it's looking for  .#main.cpp and how to fix it...

Comment: You are using file GLOB. If you have a such file move it out of the path.

Comment: Using `GLOB` is not recommended in CMake; if possible it is best to list out each source file explicitly. That will help prevent unwanted files from being added like in this situation. :)

Comment: Can you try adding `message("GTEST_SRC_FILES: ${GTEST_SRC_FILES})` and `message("APP_SRC_FILES_EXCEPT_MAIN: ${APP_SRC_FILES_EXCEPT_MAIN})` to your CMake to see what is printed?

Comment: `CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:55:
  Syntax Warning in cmake code at column 10

  Argument not separated from preceding token by whitespace.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

GTEST_SRC_FILES: /home/ics45c/projects/proj1/gtest/gtestmain.cpp)
message(APP_SRC_FILES_EXCEPT_MAIN:/home/ics45c/projects/proj1/app/.#main.cpp` Here is the result of adding the message @squareskittles

Comment: @squareskittles Also can you also give me an example of how I would list each source file explicity. I'm afraid I'm not sure of how to do this syntax correctly. I simply replaced line 20: `file(GLOB APP_SRC_FILES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/app/*.cpp)` with `file(/home/ics45c/projects/proj1/app)` but it didn't work and produced a bunch  of errors including: `CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:20 (file):
  file must be called with at least two arguments.'

Comment: Eventually, you need to list all source files in the `add_executable` call. Would you use `file(GLOB)` for that or not is irrelevant. But when using glob make sure it doesn't collect the wrong files. You may always check the list of files, collected by glob, with `message` call as suggested in the previous comments.

Comment: Is your file named `.#main.cpp` or `#main.cpp#`? I'm unclear as to which one is correct. Also, files beginning with a `.` are often hidden by *default* on Linux systems. What is the output of `ls -a` in your `app` folder?

Comment: I am thinking whatever it is named you don't want this file in the list anyways. Hopefully whatever IDE / text editor you are using does not name files like this when they are opened this may interfere with CMake if you are going to do FILE( GOBB ..) if the OP still wants globbing they may have to filter the list before the `add_executable()` it would be interesting to see the output that was requested in a previous comment.

Comment: With all of this said the question will likely not be answered without further info from the OP.