# CMake cannot find source file, but file was not specified in CMakeLists.txt, in TFS build definition

Tags: linux, tfs, cmake, tfsbuild

I'm porting a large project to linux. I wrote all the CMakeLists.txt files, and everything compiles in my machine.

For whatever reason we still use TFS. The old version, not git with TFS.

I'm working in my own branch, but that branch has no build definition for linux. Before I check in, I want to be sure that everything compiles on the server too. So I need to merge my branch to another one, and submit that shelve set to the build job.

In my machine everything compiles fine. But when I run the build in the server, applying a shelveset to the branch that has a linux build definition, I get an error from the build, saying

```
CMake Error at 
/myproject/subproject/CMakeLists.txt:165 (add_library):
  Cannot find source file:

/myproject/subproject/IInternalTransactionManager.h

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm
  .hpp .hxx .in .txx
```

Indeed, that file is not there. Cmake complains about the file not being in the sources directory, which is true, because it is in another directory. But the fact is that I'm not asking for it either! My CMakeFiles.txt file does not include that file. That file is a header which is used in a few files, contains only classes definitions (no implementations), and the directory in which myHeader.h resides has been defined in include_directories. My CMakeLists.txt looks something like this:

```
set(PROJECT_NAME project)
project(${PROJECT_NAME})
include_directories(
  ../_include
)

set(source_files
  main.cpp
  file_that_includes_myHeader.cpp
)

add_library( ${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${source_files} )
```

and my file structure is something like:

```
/myproject/subproject/main.cpp
/myproject/subproject/file_that_includes_myHeader.cpp
/myproject/subproject/CMakeLists.txt
/myproject/_include/myHeader.h
```

So, why should cmake complaining about a missing file, if such file is not included in the CMakeLists.txt file? And why would this happen only the build in TFS? My guess is that there is something wrong when applying the shelvetset and is not related to my code, but I cannot prove it.

I compared the code after the shelveset is applyied, and still in that version the CMakeLists.txt does not mention myHeader.h

Or, there is some rule about including headers in CMakeLists.txt files which I'm not aware of.

Comment: CMake won't complain about the file which is not noted in `CMakeLists.txt`. As CMake reports an error, then you have noted that file *somewhere*. It could be that your TFS server is configured in a way so it takes some `CMakeLists.txt` from old revisions. It could be many other reasons. You could inspect logs more carefully and try to find a source of that "ghost" header. You could try many modifications of your project and check which modification causes the error and which does not. Yes, some things are hard to debug. But Stack Overflow doesn't help you in that.

Comment: BTW, for file `/home/user/whatever/myproject/_include/myHeader.h` you write that `Indeed, that file is not there.`. But below you note a file `/myproject/_include/myHeader.h` as belonging to your file structure. So, do you have this file or not? Imprecise facts are bad when the error is difficult to find.

Comment: It complains about the file not being in the source directory, while the file is actually in the _include directory with other interfaces. I made a mistake in the question sorry. Just fixed it.

Comment: "It complains about the file not being in the source directory" - No, this is not the reason of CMake complain. With such error message CMake usually complains about files **explicitly** passed to `add_executable` or `add_library` and which are just absent on the disk. See e.g. the error message in that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58533026/cannot-find-source-file-error-when-running-cmake. BTW, as you can see from that question, the error message is **much more detailed** than you show.

Comment: There is no CMakeLists.txt with that file in the whole project, which is about 50G big. That file has NOT been passed to add_library or add_executable. Yes, it is when adding a library. Is that helpfull? I updated the question just in case. BTW, that question has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: According to your error message, CMake expects the file `IInternalTransactionManager.h` is placed in the same directory as your `CMakeLists.txt`. And that by itself conflicts with your project's layout, where you have the header file in the subdirectory. One more imprecise fact... Note, that CMake prints the location `/myproject/subproject/CMakeLists.txt:165` of `add_library` which **creates** the target with absent source. But given source could be added in **other line**. E.g. with `target_sources` command, or by writing into `SOURCES` property, or linking with a library with PUBLIC sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after expending too much debuging I contacted the team in charge of the build process. And as it turns out, the building process in the TFS building definition was definetly NOT what I expected. And of course this was not documented.

Our development is mostly in windows (by far). The linux build has a step before building: a script is launched which parses each Visual Studio project file, gets the included files, and substitutes the source files in the CMakeLists.txt files with the one parsed from VS. Right or wrong, is just the way it is.

I could build the linux build in my local machine because everything was done correctly. The windows build worked too, even though the VS project files sometimes included some files which were not in the source directory but in some header only directory, and somehow that compiled. I guess because the directory was defined in the include directory. But When the CMakeLists.txt files were updated, cmake complained (rightly so) about not finding the files.

So, if anybody experiences similar issues, contact your devops team or whoever is in charge of such things.